# Can anyone help me decipher these few lines? Also, converting this code for a 2x2 matrix input to a 3x3 matrix input?

Tags: matrix

Here's the code. I'm completely new to Mathematica so bear with me.

```
clear[ug];
ug[{{a11_, a12_}, {a21_, a22_}}] := 
 Module[{A, f, b1, b2, y1, y2, U, P1, P2, UG}, 
  A = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}};
  f[x_] := A.x;
  b1 = A.{1, 0};
  b2 = A.{0, 1};
  y1 = Table[Line[{k b1 - 4 b2, k b1 + 4 b2}], {k, -4, 4}];
  y2 = Table[Line[{-4 b1 + k b2, 4 b1 + k b2}], {k, -4, 4}];
  hougan = {Thickness[0.002], {Dashing[{0.01}], y1, y2}};
  U = {{-3, 3}, {-3, -3}, {0, -3}, {0, 3}, {-1, 3}, {-1, -2}, {-2, -2}, {-2, 3}, {-3, 3}};
  P1 = {{0, -3}, {1, -3}, {3, -3}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, -3}};
  P2 = {{1, -2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {1.5, -1}, {1.5, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, -2}};
  UG = {hougan, {Darker[Green, .55], Polygon[Map[f, U]]}, {Black, 
       Polygon[Map[f, P1]]}, {White, Polygon[Map[f, P2]]}};
  Show[Graphics[{UG}], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
       AspectRatio -> Automatic]]

  A := {{3/4, 1/12}, {3/4, 3/4}}; Eigensystem[A]

  Animate[ug[MatrixPower[A, n]], {n, 0, 10, 1}]
```

The goal of this code is supposed to input a 2x2 matrix, and be able to visualize the map v(sub)k = (A^k)v(sub)0, where v(sub)0 = [{x(sub)0},{y(sub)0}], for any A.

What I'm confused with are a few things:

- b1 and b2. Am I correct that this multiplies A by [1 0], so b1 is the first row of A and b2 is the second row?
- y1 and y2. Completely confused what these two lines do.
- hougan. Also no idea at all.
- UG. Can someone break this down for me? Especially what these kinds of bits do: Polygon[Map[f, U]].

Here is what (I think) I have to do so far for converting this from a 2x2 matrix input into a 3x3 matrix input.

- Change ug, A, U, P1, and P2 into 3x3 matrices.
- Change b1 = A.{1,0,0};, b2 = A.{0,1,0};, and add a b3 = A.{0,0,1};.
- Change Graphics in the Show line to Graphics3D.

Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Oops yeah I should have clarified that. Edited!

Comment: I'll clarify what [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) does, but first note that `U` and friends are *not* matrices -- they are lists of vectors.  `Map[f,U]` acts the function `f` on each of those vectors, returning a list of the results.  Given the definition of `f`, `Map[f,U]` does `{A.u1, A.u2, ... }` for `U={u1, u2, ...}`.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) -- it's Mathematica's go-to way of constructing lists.  So `y1` and `y2` are making lists of `Line`s.  `hougan` is just giving some formatting for those lists of lines in the form `Graphics` is expecting.  You shouldn't need to understand this in detail to make the modifications you need to make.

Comment: Any more details on what y1 and y2 do? Am I correct in assuming that, for example y1, (k b1 - 4 b2) calculates a vector that acts as the first point, and (k b1 + 4 b2) is the second point and Line connects the two? Also, any idea why these particular expressions are used to find each point and how I would go about changing these expressions for my 3x3 program?

Comment: I think you can answer the question yourself by looking at the documentation for `Line`.  (That's what I just did to make sure my impressions of the Line function were correct.)  Moreover, getting in the habit of doing this will be good for you.  Also, please [ping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#replying-in-comments) me with @jjc385 when you reply to my comments, so I get notified.

Comment: As for why these particular points are computed, I'm unsure.  However, this is certainly a good way (arguably the best way) to compute the vectors `{A.u1, A.u2, ... }`, given a list of vectors `{u1, u2, ...}`.  You'd certainly need to make the `u1` etc 3-element vectors in your 3x3 program.

Comment: `A.{1, 0}` should be clear from the second of the "Basic Examples" in the documentation for `Dot`.  Likewise, you should spend some time investigating each line.